# How to 'exit' in the node.js version of Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I want to call the session.endDialog whenever the user inputs 'exit' as the message.

Currently, my bot has many types of dialogues, but i want the bot to end the conversation when the 'exit' is typed by the user regardless of which dialogue the user is currently in.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to use [triggerAction](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.dialog.html#triggeraction) along with [endConversation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/session/#ending-conversations) (instead of endDialog):

```
// reset the bot 
bot.dialog('reset', function (session) {
    // reset data
    session.endConversation("Ok… Goodbye.");
}).triggerAction({ matches: /^exit/i });
```

Comment: oh it works! thanks you so much. by the way, how do I add the words that triggers this action? Also, how can I call a different dialog using triggerAction instead of ending the convo?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it understand the 'intents' (from LUIS) to trigger the event instead of hardcoding the keyword?

Comment: To have multiple trigger words, just have groups separated by | in the matches regular expression: `matches: /^(exit)|(quit)|(depart)|(move away)/i`

Comment: The code in the answer already makes a new dialog with the id 'reset'. You would just change the code in the function to do whatever you would like.

To use LUIS intents, you need to add the LUIS recognizer to the bot, via `bot.recognizer(new builder.LuisRecognizer(url)`, then set the triggerAction's matches attribute to a string of the intent's name, `matches: "IntentName"`. You may have issues if you're in a dialog that uses the same Luis recognizer, though. I found having two Luis apps, one for a specific dialogue and one for all input, worked well.

Comment: dialog.matches('greeting', [ .... // this is how i started the dialog that recognizes luis intent 'greeting'. If I want a triggerAction that recognizes the 'greeting' intent, how shall I change this??

Comment: Just follow the answer's code, replacing the single function with your array of functions, and the regular expression with a string of your intent name. And make sure you've added the Luis recognizer to the bot object, as stated in my second comment.